# I am trying to direct print my report

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual studio 2015. and trying to print my report. my Preview report its working good. but when i am trying to Direct print then its default print of crystal report. i think my function is wrong. 
somebody please help me. thanks you.

**This is my Preview Code (its Working Good):**

```
Private Function GetDeliveryChallanPreviewPrint() As DataTable
    Dim Data As New DataTable
    Using conn
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from DcMaster dm
Left join DcDetail dd on dm.ID = dd.ID where dm.id = '" & PrinByIDTextBox.Text.ToString() & "'", conn)
            conn.Open()
            Using adp As New SqlDataAdapter
                adp.SelectCommand = cmd
                adp.Fill(Data)
                Dim DcPrint As New Rpt_DeliveryChallan
                Dim FILEPATH As String = CurDir() & "\Reports\Rpt_DeliveryChallan.rpt"
                DcPrint.Load(FILEPATH)
                DcPrint.SetDataSource(Data)
                CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = DcPrint
                CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
                StatusLabel.Visible = False
                conn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

**This is my Direct Print Code: (its not Working) Please Help me.**

```
Private Function GetDeliveryChallanDirectPrint() As DataTable
    Dim Data As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("VKDBx").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from DcMaster dm
Left join DcDetail  dd  on dm.ID = dd.ID where dm.id = '" & PrinByIDTextBox.Text.ToString() & "'", conn)
            conn.Open()
            Using adp As New SqlDataAdapter
                adp.SelectCommand = cmd
                adp.Fill(Data)

                Dim DcPrint As New Rpt_DeliveryChallan
                Dim FILEPATH As String = CurDir() & "\Reports\Rpt_DeliveryChallan.rpt"

                DcPrint.PrintOptions.PrinterName = PrinterComboBox.Text
                DcPrint.Load(FILEPATH)
                DcPrint.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0)
                DcPrint.SetDataSource(Data)
                conn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Its Done.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am doing successfully. just some changing place `PrintTOPrinter` line Down.

```
Private Function GetDeliveryChallanPrint() As DataTable
    Dim Data As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(_SqlCon)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from DcMaster dm
Left join DcDetail  dd  on dm.ID = dd.ID where dm.id = '" & PrintByIDLabel.Text.ToString() & "'", conn)
            conn.Open()
            Using adp As New SqlDataAdapter
                adp.SelectCommand = cmd
                adp.Fill(Data)

                Dim Printrpt As New Rpt_DeliveryChallan
                Dim FILEPATH As String = CurDir() & "\Reports\Rpt_DeliveryChallan.rpt"

                Printrpt.PrintOptions.PrinterName = PrinterComboBox.Text
                Printrpt.Load(FILEPATH)
                Printrpt.SetDataSource(Data)
                Printrpt.PrintToPrinter(NumberOfCopiesNumericUpDown.Value, False, 0, 0)

            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```